# nodejs fs.watch async way

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I try to figure out what file in a folder is changed while upload files. For this I tried to use fs.watch. I use

```
const watcher = fs.watch(watchDir, (eventname, filename) => {
  console.log("Watcher: " + filename);
});

//Code
const getCookie = ClientFunction(() => {
    return document.cookie;
});
let xmlresult = await helpers.getXMLInfo('', testCorpusid, caseid);
console.log("Test message");
//Code

watcher.close()
```

But it looks like that nothing inside the //Code part is not executed. I think something I misunderstand here, right? Can anybody give me a hint how to watch a folder async?

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the desired code to run on each file change inside the callback function, like this:

```
const watcher = fs.watch(watchDir, async (eventname, filename) => {
  console.log("Watcher: " + filename);

  const getCookie = ClientFunction(() => {
      return document.cookie;
  });
  let xmlresult = await helpers.getXMLInfo('', testCorpusid, caseid);
  console.log("Test message");
});
```

Read more about callbacks [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function).

Comment: This I also tried out but this will not allow to use await....

Comment: @ingo Regarding not being allowed to use `await` - is the function marked as `async` ???